# Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) always returns camera position, doesnt matter where i click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am trying to create a script that converts mouseclick position into position in GridLayout. I trying to use Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(), but its returning coordinates of camera, not of the point clicked, doesnt metter if i use static camera or camera fixed on player. I attached this script to CharacterRobotBoy prefab from standard unity assets.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Position : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            Vector3 pz = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            Debug.Log("camera:"+pz);
            pz.z = 0;
            GridLayout gridLayout = transform.parent.GetComponentInParent<GridLayout>();
            Vector3Int cellPosition = gridLayout.WorldToCell(pz);
            Debug.Log("cell position:"+cellPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

Can my code be fixed for the task, or is there a different solution for the problem. Thanks for your help.
PS: I am new to unity.

Comment: dropping everything starting the line pz.z = 0.. your code is returning my mouse location.. are you sure your camera is set main?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity obtaining Vector of click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663474/unity-obtaining-vector-of-click-event)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a flat plane and a camera looking at it from above.
Think of the screen as the lens of the camera, and the cursor as a small ant walking over it. If I remember correctly, ScreenToWorldPoint returns the location of the ant in world-space, which is somewhere in the sky. By setting z := 0, you get a point directly below the camera, regardless of where the cursor is.

What you should do instead is cast a ray from the center of the camera-view through the ant, and collide it with the plane. The collision point is what you are looking for. 
It can be done via the ScreenPointToRay method.

You should check out [Brackeys RPG tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2mK6KFdv0I), he's done something similar.

Hope it helps :)